# How we use G1ANT.Addon.Msoffice in real life?

Tags: rpa, g1ant, robotics-studio

How we used this format in real life and what is the benefit to used it?

Comment: What does the term "real life" mean in this context? Please add a bit more context as to what's triggered this question for you.

Answer (score -1):

It can be used to copy data from online sites to our own excel or word file and save it locally so that it can be accessed further without requirement of internet.